# GDAL error in QGIS: "Interpreting GDAL error: "gdal_rasterize: symbol lookup error: gdal_rasterize: undefined symbol: CheckExtensionConsistency"?

Tags: qgis, gdal-rasterize

I'm using QGIS 3.4.6 with GDAL/OGR 2.3.1 to rasterize a points shapefile with the gdal_rasterize tool, and I keep getting the error 'Interpreting GDAL error: "gdal_rasterize: symbol lookup error: gdal_rasterize: undefined symbol: CheckExtensionConsistency"'.

What's going on here?  How do I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Please edit your question to specify how and from where you installed QGIS and what operating system you use.

Answer (score 1):

The GDAL version you have installed is the same to the one mentioned in [THIS](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/848) post. Basically they suggest that uninstalling (all) GDAL versions and installing the 2.2.3 version has solved the issue.

At this point in time you haven't specified your OS so not sure if the solution they've suggested in that post is going to be relevant to your problem.